# how to implement leverage browser caching

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications, browser-cache

I am trying to implement **browse caching** to speed up my application. But i am a newbie in this area. Can anybody tell me how to do this?

I am using tomcat for my application, my application is in java and on windows.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can instruct (request) browser to cache some static files from your web app so that browser won't make actual request each time  by adding a Filter that sets header for static file serving

refer to one such [`Cache-Filter`](http://code.google.com/p/cache-filter/wiki/CacheFilter)